# How can I install Gphoto2?

Tags: kubuntu, photo, photography, gphoto2

I'm new to (K)ubuntu. Does anybody know how to install the gphoto2 software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 8):

Wow, how is the documentation for this so terrible? At the time of writing, the documentation on the [official site](http://www.gphoto.org/doc/manual/configure-make-install.html) literally says:

```
5.3. Configuring, building, and installing
WRITEME :-P (PKG_CONFIG_PATH, ./configure, make, make install, /etc/ld.so.conf, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PATH, yadda yadda)
```

Here's how I installed it (on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) after lots of trial and error. Keep in mind that `gphoto2` is simply the CLI for `libgphoto2`. Simply installing `gphoto2` won't do much for you.

### Easy method

Use `apt` (or `apt-get`)

```
$ sudo apt install gphoto2
$ sudo apt install libgphoto2-6
```

You may be wondering why it's `libgphoto2-6` and not just `libgphoto2`. When you're typing `sudo apt install libgphoto2` press `tab` and see what it completes. You can also view what the latest packages are for each ubuntu build. [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgphoto2) and [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gphoto2).

After that you should be able to use gphoto2 in Terminal.

```
$ gphoto2 -v
```

should show you something meaningful.

### Advanced build

If you go to the gphoto2 website, you'll notice that they've released updates to `libgphoto2` since Ubuntu 18.04's latest package (2.5.16). Specifically, I want to have support for Sony Alpha A9, which requires `libgphoto2 v2.5.22`. You can download it from the [source](http://www.gphoto.org/), but now what?

`cd` to the tar.bz2 file.

**unzip it**: autocomplete the file name by pressing `tab`

```
$ tar -xjf libgphoto2-2.5.22.tar.bz2
```

**configure, make, make install** Go into the directory. Each of these commands will take time, so enter one line at a time.

```
$ cd libgphoto2-2.5.22

$ autoreconf -is
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

If at any point it says it looks like something went wrong, it's likely you're missing a package. I had to install: `libtool`, `libpopt-dev`, `libsub-dev`, `libexif-dev`, `libjpeg-dev`, `autoconf`, `autopoint`, `libcdk5-dev`

The github repo has an additional step of

```
autoreconf -is
```

which for me, required `apt install`ing the `autoconf` and `autopoint` packages.

This updates `libgphoto2`. To [update](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gphoto/files/gphoto/) `gphoto2`, which I needed to do in order to use libgphoto2-2.5.22, you have to go through the same steps. Read the README.md. I had to install `libpopt-dev`. Running `./configure` alerted me to this problem.

You may need to restart Terminal or your machine to see changes.

After that, check your version using `gphoto2 -v`.

Comment: I believe "libsub-dev" should be "libusb-dev"

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt install gphoto2 libgphoto2*
```

This should do it.

Comment: It works, GPhoto2 is downloaded, but how to open it? (Sorry for my stupidness) (sorry for my english too) Thanks #Cheese129

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? I learned that without libgphoto2, Ubuntu does not recognize SD cards with photos on it. I have never tried to control a camera through gphoto2, though.

Comment: I want to try to control a camera with gphoto2. But when i search for gphoto2 in the pc, there is no program called that. When i tries to install it again, it says it is downloaded. What to do? Thanks #Cheese129

Comment: I suggest opening another question here on askubuntu, because that's a different topic. Another idea is asking on https://photo.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I have now opened a new topic:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/905453/have-installedd-gphoto2-but-how-to-open-it

Answer (score 1):

`gphoto2-updater` (https://github.com/gonzalo/gphoto2-updater) compiles from the latest github source of gphoto2.

Comment: brilliant shortcut!